# REST API - what is the proper way for sending ID on http request?

Tags: rest, httprequest

Let's say I have this URI endpoint:

```
:GET /v1/permissions
```

Which select all of the permissions on version 1.

One also can request this:

```
:GET /permissions
```

Which will request all permissions by the latest default version.

Now I want to select all of the permissions from a **specific** user.

I want to know what is the proper and respectable way to send the identifier of the user - in the URI endpoint OR in the http request headers OR as a GET param.

For example:

Method 1:

```
:GET /v1/groups/:id/permissions
```

Method 1.1:

```
:GET /v1/:id/permissions
```

Method 2:

```
:GET /v1/permissions,
"If-Match": "[REPLACE_ID_HERE]" (header)
```

Method 3:

```
:GET /v1/permissions/?groups=REPLACE_ID_HERE
```

All of them will work.

But which is the proper way?

Comment: Headers prefixed with `If-` are meant for [conditional requests](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232). The value of [`If-Match`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-3.1) should be an _entity tag_, so it's unsuitable for sending a resource identifier. Other scenarios are addressed in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52623017/1426227).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But which is the proper way?

It's a **common misconception**.

The REST architectural style doesn't enforce any URI design <sup>(see notes below)</sup>. It's totally up to you to pick the URIs that better identify your *resources*.

---

The URI syntax is defined in the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). As general rule, the path is organized in *hierarchical* form (with segments separated by `/`) and can contain non-hierarchical data in the query component (starting with `?`).

These approaches seem to be fine to identify *the permissions of a particular group*:

- `/v1/groups/:id/permissions`
- `/v1/permissions?groups=id`

The *"right"* approach would depend on your needs and how you model your API. In the first approach, the hierarchy expresses that the permissions belong to a particular group (the permissions *depend* on a group to exist). The second approach is more like *filtering a collection of permissions by group*.

---

<sup>**Note 1:** The REST architectural style is described in the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Roy T. Fielding's dissertation and it defines a set of constraints that must be followed by the applications that follow such architecture. However it says nothing about what the URIs must be like.</sup>

<sup>**Note 2:** The *examples* of a [popular article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) written by Martin Fowler explaining a model defined by Leonard Richardson *suggest* a URI structure that looks friendly and easy to read.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Two points upfront:

- There is no official REST specification issued by a central authority. The entire paradigm originates from a rather slim (yet ingenious) technical outline written by Roy Fielding in the year 2000.
- However, there are several good books on the matter and hundreds of thousands of implementations that have led to a **firm industry standard**.

One of those standards is that **REST Urls are specific to resources** and ids embedded in those Urls reference resources of the same type. Thus `GET /groups/:groupdId` is *orthodox* (a standard implementation that matches the expectations of most programmers) whereas `GET /groups/:permissionId` is not.

Coming back to the 4 alternatives you contemplate:

**Method 1:**

```
:GET /v1/groups/:id/permissions
```

Is orthodox, since the resource managed by the endpoint is of type `Group` and :id is a Group id.

**Method 1.1:**

```
:GET /v1/:id/permissions
```

Is unorthodox since there is no indication of what resource type the Url refers to.

**Method 2:**

```
:GET /v1/permissions,
"If-Match": "[REPLACE_ID_HERE]" (header)
```

Is unorthodox, since resource ids are expected to be passed as part of the Url.

**Method 3:**

```
:GET /v1/permissions/?groups=REPLACE_ID_HERE
```

Is orthodox, since here the resource is `Permission` and the `groupId` is applied as a filter, for which request parameters are the adequate means.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way of designing a REST API is following the resources (and - or sub-resources) structure. i.e. api url will start with your resource name followed by a unique ID for the resource in case of Single resource GET, PUT(update) or DELETE.

Ex : 
1. /users/$unique_user_id - HTTP GET - Fetches the single user detail.

2. /users/$unique_user_id - HTTP PUT - updates the user details identified by the id with the related data.
3. /users/$unique_user_id - HTTP DELETE - Deletes the user identified by the ID.

If your case handles a **well established relation** between 2 resources you can handle them as sub-resources of the parent.
Ex : 
/users/$user_id/permissions 
/groups/$group_id/permissions

This model will suit if you won’t get a requirement to fetch permissions for **multiple resources**(kind of filtering)
Ex : 
/permissions?group_ids=1,2,3
/permissions?user_ids=4,5,6

Answer (score -2):

As per REST spec, you first need to determine what is the base resource you are requesting for. The name of the resource comes first in the URI. In your case, it's the Permission. Hence the URI will begin with permission, with an optional version prefix (as the whole API is versioned)

Following the resource name, you need to mention either a specific resource or a query parameters to get a broad list. Now here you have two options, based on what you are retrieving.
1) permission for a person: In this case, you need to put query param as the api itself won't be able to guess what is the id for. Hence it will be permissions/?personId=123
2) permission detail of a particular permission: Used when you have a list of permissions pre fetched, maybe as result of above api. In this case the identifier will belong to the resource itself, hence it will be specified as the resource identifier as permissions/5e55 where 5e55 is the primary key of the specified permission of whom detail is being sought after.

The major complexity in such design is properly identify the resource primary identifier and secondary identifier...
The primary identifier is put directly in type 2 and secondary is specified as query param.

All said, technically nothing will stop the either request style from working as long as you provide the parsing logic of the URI. REST just says that URI should be able to identify resource properly and does not impose an implementation requirement.

Comment: _"As per REST spec, you first need to determine what is the base resource you are requesting for. The name of the resource comes first in the URI."_ Where in the _REST spec_ you found that?

Comment: It all starts with one resource in hand and then finding related resources. Also about which api we are manipulating. Id or query params are just means of constraining the set of resources just like the where clause in sql.. The table name remains same as the relevant entity

Comment: First, REST does not really have a spec as this is an architectural design pattern rather than an industry standard or protocol. Next, REST actually does not put any emphasis on how an URI pointing to a resource should look like. You might even encrypt parts of the URL or tiny the URL as a whole as long as the request is able to finally reach the server. Assuming URIs to need to be pretty in REST is just wrong. In a REST architecture the structure of the URI is actually not of importance as clients should determine whether to invoke it via an accompanying, meaningful link-relation name

Comment: Agree about REST not as a spec, sorry for that. But rest maturity level ensures that it's resource focused and taking the uri own structure, we parse it left to right... Protocol server, api, resource and then filters. Second, rest is meant for easy maintenance of api which requires them to be pretty, as how would u handle complex and variant formats?

Comment: Also, the request will be able to reach server as long as the server parsing logic matches the uri structure, whatsoever bad. But all patterns emphasize beautiful design as their basic purpose

Comment: REST allows servers/API to evolve freely without risking clients to break due to server changes. This property, however, can only be achived if, and only if, they follow a certain rule-set precisely. By removing out-of-band information a client might need in order to interact with your service, you basically decouple it from your API and make it more robust. I.e. clients shouldn't parse or generate URIs but use the ones the server provided. This allows servers to change URIs on the fly. Link relation names give such URIs meaning, and media-type allow for robust interoperability of the data

Comment: You can design URIs however you like. But it doesn't make an API (or the URIs) more or less RESTful. A "beautiful" URI might give humans some sense what the resource might actually contain, though you also risk in ending up with [typed resources meaningful to clients](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html). Similar to the browser-based Web you aren't interested in how the URI is made up but that the text describing the URIs content is expressful enough to let you decide whether you want to invoke that URI or not - the same holds true for REST